# How to disable oembed cache service?

Tags: oembed

Today I delete all **oembed records** by **postmeta** `where meta_key like '_oembed%'`

after 5 mins, check again the table, magic, the wordpress started to insert _oembed records again (9857 total)...

Can someone tell how can I disable this ??

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's important for performance.

Comment: I would like to disable completely the oEmbed. The WP will get performance once is not writing to **_postmeta** table...

Comment: Do you want to disable the oembed _cache_ or oembed entirely? They're different things and you need to be precise. Disabling the cache without disabling oembed will cause big performance problems.

Comment: yes please, I would like to disable the **oembed entirely**. Can you guide me as I couldnt find such information around web. FYI Before I delete the records described above^ to main post, I applied to **functions.php** [these](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-embeds-wordpress/).